# How to remove black and white square background which is appearing behind the sprite in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have an image having only layer 1 with no background

[image]

when i am importing this in unity then the black and white square background is still appearing

[image]

I want only the circle  an not the whole square image.

How I can remove the black and white square background so that only the circle appears on the screen?

Comment: I see the name of the asset is "circle.jpg". JPEG files don't have transparency, but I am surpsised to see the chequerboard pattern which is normally used to indicate transparency. Was it obtained as a screengrab instead of saving as PNG (or a vector format)?

Comment: No, it is not obtained as screen grab I have saved the file and then imported it to unity.

Comment: @MohammadAL-Haque yes but as said already JPEG has no alpha layer ... only PNG

Comment: so I have to save the image in png format and then import it to unity?

Comment: @MohammadAL-Haque Yes, save it in png format.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have added a image of png format then also same problem is occuring

Comment: If this still happens it seems like the checkmark layer is actually a layer in your program (seems to be Photoshop?) that is actually in there ... or simply already existent in the image file's pixel data if you downloaded it as JPG from somewhere ... In this case you could probably just select the black circle and Crop

Comment: @MohammadAL-Haque [Apparently](https://www.reddit.com/r/krita/comments/4dejp6/transparent_images/), in Krita, "When saving to PNG keep in mind that you need to make sure the "Store Alpha Channel (transparency) checkbox is checked.""

Comment: I found my mistake @derHugo you are right that checkmark layer is part of the photo

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you for your helping me out